# Is it possible to manually update the nginx version of an Elastic Beanstalk Node.js environment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node.js application running on 64bit Amazon Linux on Elastic Beanstalk, which uses nginx 1.18.0 ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.nodejs )

Our security department requires us now to use nginx 1.21.0 which is not supported even by 64bit Amazon Linux 2 AMIs. Is it possible to upgrade nginx version manually? I have checked documentation but couldn't find anything regarding that.